# How can we get a specific attribute of random position?

Tags: gdal, pyqgis, ogr, fields-attributes, s-57

I am working on S57 chart. I want to apply *star shortest path algorithm on the S57 chart. Each node (position) should be defined whether is available for navigate or not. So at least each node should be on the sea.(whether on *SEAARE layer or not).

*S57 have different layer such as SEAARE which define sea water. And each layer  has OBJL attribute (SEAARE OBJL =119). This is specific integer number to define the layer.

[image]  Pink area:Island - Blue area: sea. I want to detect by using API any random position on chart is navigatable(OBJL=119,blue) or obstacle(LNDARE OBJL=71,land)

I think that I can realize position on the sea using OBJL attribute but I don't know how I get these information from s57 for any position.

In short, I use QGIS and Python language for programming. How can I detect any attribute (like OBJL) for any random position (lat/long) on chart by using pyqgis or GDAL/OGR API?

If you have any idea of other file format, I can convert s57 to *shapefile or PostgreSQL*. Also I am quite new to GIS.

Comment: Ask the captain to look out of the window? if he can see cars etc you have run aground.